# Table Select does not work in Model Builder, when using parameter in SQL

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, geoprocessing

I'm trying to create a model that uses values from a single table, in order to perform a different calculation for each raster in a file.
Each raster is represented in the table by a row that contains the raster unique name (string), and 2 other fields with the numeric values for the calculation (slope & intercept).
I use "Iterate rasters" to go through the files, and "Table Select" where I select the relevant row for the parameters, by using %Name% (from the iterator) = name (the raster name in the table).
Doesn't work... the model gets stuck in the "Table Select" stage.
Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Would you be able to include a picture of a test model illustrating what you are trying to describe in words, please?  Also, as a new user, be sure to take the 2-minute [Tour] to learn about the site.

Answer (score 2):

As @PolyGeo say you need to upload an image of your model to be crystal clear because as I read it you are saying when you use the Table Select tool you are putting into the where clause parameter the following query:

> %Name% = **name**

Assuming **name** is the name of the field holding the name of the raster then I think your where clause should be:

> name = "%Name%"